# Scraping with Python from type="submit"

Tags: python, web-scraping

Have been trying to set up code for scraping a web page in Python. However, I can't find the code, that helps me identify the "Submit" button in the source code of the web page. See the source code here:

[Source code of the web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Xji.png)

What I have tried so far includes:

```
log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.submit')

log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Log in')

log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('buttonstyle__Button-sc-11cbuc5-1 kfFBYh styled__SubmitButton-sc-voms4e-4 jPKYnl')
```

Also have tried the following, it works, but then a different button to the one I want (in the code it is before the button that I want) is clicked.

```
log_in_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button')
```

Any suggestions on what else I could try, besides the mentioned?
Sorry if I haven't got the terminology 100% correct yet, just starting out here. Hope it is clear nevertheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.submit')
```

This does describe button element with class submit, i.e. something like `<button class="submit">` whilst you have button with `submit` type, which in CSS selector language is `button[type=submit]`, so your code shoule be

```
log_in_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[type=submit]')
```